# Incorrect formula rendering with MathJax

Tags: javascript, latex, formula, mathjax

I'm trying to render some formulas without success. The formula in question is

```
\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N k^2}{a}
```

It must be something with how I configure MathJax, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Here it is:

```
window.MathJax.Hub.Config({
  config: ['MMLorHTML.js'],
  MMLorHTML: { prefer: { Firefox: 'MML', other:   'SVG' } },
  displayAlign: 'left',
  extensions: ['asciimath2jax.js', 'tex2jax.js', 'mml2jax.js', 'MathMenu.js', 'MathZoom.js'],
  jax: ['input/TeX', 'input/AsciiMath', 'input/MathML', 'output/SVG', 'output/NativeMML'],
  messageStyle: 'none',
  showMathMenu: false,
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  skipStartupTypeset: true,
  'HTML-CSS': {linebreaks: {automatic: true}}
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfrrf/23/) which demonstrates the issue. The formula should be rendered as follows: [image]

Any suggestions what is missing in my configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LaTex inline math you have to use `\(` and `\)` instead of backticks:

```
el2.html('\\(\\frac{\\displaystyle \\sum_{k=1}^N k^2}{a}\\)');
```

gives the desired result.

The backtick is per default the asciimath delimiter (see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/asciimath.html) and `\(` the TeX delimiter (see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html).

Alternatively you could reconfigure the delimiters with

```
  asciimath2jax: {delimiters: []},
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['`','`']]},
```